# How To style a Django formset for fileField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have this formset.

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Post, user = request.user, slug = slug )
files = file.objects.all().filter(Post=instance)
FormSet = modelformset_factory(file, fields=('file',), can_delete=True)
formset=FormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, queryset=files)
```

models.py:

```
class file(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_location, blank = True, null = True)
    Post = models.ForeignKey(Post, blank = True, null = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = True, null = True)

    def filename(self):
        f = self.file.name
        f1 = f.split('/', 3)[-1]
        return f1

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

thats how i used it in my template:

```
 {{ formset.management_form }}
 {% for form in formset %}
 {{form.file}}
 {{form.DELETE.label}}
 {{form.DELETE}}
 {% endfor %}
```

and it shows like this in my browser:

[image: look]

i tried every this but i could not able to to get rid of currently and i literally do not know how to style this. please help me guys.

Comment: with some CSS ?

Comment: i tried it but it is not working

Comment: i just need to know how to separate the fields in forms because i cant figure it out.

Comment: you want only one file field?

Comment: file field and delete checkbox .